# Appium: App Path only works with a direct link?

Tags: appium

I'm using Laravel php and Appium.

I want Appium to download the .apk/.ipa file from a certain route which returns the downloaded file.

> App path in Appium: localhost/downloadApp

```
public function downloadApp(Request $request) {
...
return response()->download($path);
}
```

If I try this way, it doesn't work and I get an error "[Support] Error: Plist file doesn't exist: '.../Info.plist". I don't know why because if I call localhost/downloadApp in my browser, it downloads the file.

But if I use the direct link (http://localhost/uploads/HelloWorld.ipa) in Appium, it works.

Answer (score 0):

The path must point to an actual file.

You can download the file itself from your code but you need to make sure that:

1. The file has completed to download before you set up the driver
2. The path to the downloaded file is correct, make sure the name of the file and the download location is the same as what you set in the capabilities ("localhost/downloadApp" doesn't seem like the correct download path)

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem, I just use `return redirect ($file_path);` and that works fine for apk file. For security, I also use the POST method to start download. This is my code:

```
//blade code :

    <li class="nav-item">
        <form method="POST" action="{{url('/files/download')}}">
        {{ csrf_field()}}
        <button class="btn btn-primary fa fa-download"> download </button>
        </form>
    </li>


    //Route code : 
    Route::post('/files/download', 'FilesController@download');


    //Controller code : 

    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;  


    class FilesController extends Controller
    {

     public function download($file)
        {   
            $file_path = 'your folder path/file.apk';
// if your file in public use $path = "/your folder/file.apk"
// if your file is in out of public you may use two points like that: $path = "../your folder/file.apk" 

        return redirect ($file_path);
        }
    }
```